# Update Handle Breadcrumbs Not Working

Tags: magento, magento-layout-xml

any idea why following layout update handle is not working? i'm trying copy breadcrumbs from **customer_address_index** to **customer_address_new** and **customer_address_new**?

```
<customer_address_index>
<reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>home</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
        </action>

        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>My Account</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>My Account</label><title>My Account</title><link>/customer/account</link></crumbInfo>
        </action>

        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>Address Book</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Address Book</label><title>Address Book</title><link></link></crumbInfo>
        </action>


</reference>

</customer_address_index>


<customer_address_new>
     <reference name="breadcrumbs"> <!-- Not working -->
        <update handle="customer_address_index" />
     </reference>
</customer_address_new>

<customer_address_edit>
    <update handle="customer_address_index" /> <!-- Not working also -->
</customer_address_edit>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found why is not working, **customer_address_new** and **customer_address_new** is not exist
,i should use **customer_address_form**

here the xml code

```
<customer_address_index>
<reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>home</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
        </action>

        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>My Account</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>My Account</label><title>My Account</title><link>/customer/account</link></crumbInfo>
        </action>

        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>Address Book</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Address Book</label><title>Address Book</title><link></link></crumbInfo>
        </action>


</reference>

</customer_address_index>

<!--
Not working properly
<customer_address_form>
     <reference name="breadcrumbs"> 
        <update handle="customer_address_index" />
     </reference>
</customer_address_form>

Not working also
<customer_address_form>
    <update handle="customer_address_index" /> 
</customer_address_form>
-->

<customer_address_form>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>home</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
        </action>

        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>My Account</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>My Account</label><title>My Account</title><link>/customer/account</link></crumbInfo>
        </action>

        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>Address Book</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Address Book</label><title>Address Book</title><link></link></crumbInfo>
        </action>


</reference>
</customer_address_form>
```